# How to provide custom username for my Android library in Github?

Tags: android, github

I'm very new to create a Android library. I just tried with toast library.

This is current dummy example

Current:

implementation "**com.github.truecaller**.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk

Expected

implementation "**com.truecaller**.android:truecaller-sdk